# Using Hibernate connection with JasperReports

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports

I'm making now a new module into a big one web application. I've created in *iReport* a report with Hibernate Connection. All Hibernate classes were already made by my teammates, hql query also. So, we can say, I've made only "visual" part in designer.

In *iReport* all works great, like I wanted. I'm using hibernate.cfg.xml file where session factory is defined.

My problem began when I wanted to integrate my *.jrxml file with java web app.
Web application is made on maven using Spring Framework. So I have additional file applicationContext.xml where hibernate session factory is also defined like in hibernate.cfg.xml.

The question is, is it possible to make it's working, using @autowired on bean from applicationContext.xml?

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("binderSessionFactory")
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

If yes, how could I give this connection so it work's with my *.jrxml file?

Java code:

```
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

Map parameters = (Map) model.get("parameters");

URL reportTemplate = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("pathToFile/file.jrxml");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportTemplate.getPath());
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
```

How should I make a hibernate db connection visible for my report?

Answer (score 0):

To answer you first question, yes it is possible. Please refer to this links for the required configuration needed for the JasperReports-Hibernate integration:
[JasperReports 5.6.0 - Hibernate Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/hibernate/)  and 
[Using Hibernate queries in JasperReports](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery103/)

 While this last link is shows the specific requirement for Spring: [JasperReports - Spring MVC](http://keytotechnologies.blogspot.com/2013/02/jasper-report-spring-hibernate-example.html)

 Hope these helps.

Comment: Firts link I've read, but it didn't help, maybe because I'm using Spring also, don't know.
Second tell's about sending result from query with *.jrxml file to compile. That mean's - query inside template it's not needed, I'll try to do it that way.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115722/jasperreports-5-6-0-and-hibernate-4-nosuchfielderror-boolean I've described another one problem.